# F# Type Providers and Units of Measure

Tags: f#, type-providers, units-of-measurement

Is it possible to annotate generated properties/fields with custom units of measure?  I noticed that `ProvidedTypes.fs` provides helper methods for annotating with the built-in F# units of measure, as in the following example:

`ProvidedMeasureBuilder.AnnotateType(typedefof<int>, [ProvidedMeasureBuilder.SI "kilogram"])`

However, I do not see any clear way to annotate with a custom unit of measure that's referenced in another assembly.  Is this even possible?  Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK/blob/master/src/ProvidedTypes.fs

**UPDATE:**

The issues that I was running into apparently had nothing to do with the fact that my units of measure were custom, rather, it was because the types were generated types.  By switching to erased types, custom units were simple to implement:

`ProvidedMeasureBuilder.AnnotateType(typedefof<int>, [typedefof<SomeObjectInMyAssembly>.Assembly.GetType("Namespace.UnitOfMeasure"))`